# Не получается вставить картинку на веб-страницу

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разрабатываю небольшое веб-приложение, вставляю картинки как обычно с гугла и тут такое

Comment: Попробуй указать относительный путь: `./images/img*.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете относительный путь к файлу. Относительный путь всегда начинается с места, где хранится документ в котором этот путь прописывается.
В Вашем случае путь будет такой: ./images/(имя картинки)